# NSTableView : Context menu for editing column configuration

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

In some OS X apps, control-clicking on the header of an NSTableView brings up a context menu, that lets the user choose which columns are visible.

Is this something I'll need to implement manually, or is this some hard to find Cocoa feature?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it isn't a standard feature of NSTableView. You have to implement it on your own by setting the menu of NSTableHeaderView.

```
  NSMenu *menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@""];
  menu.font = [NSFont menuFontOfSize:[NSFont smallSystemFontSize]];
  menu.showsStateColumn = YES;
  for (NSTableColumn *column in tableView.tableColumns) {
    NSMenuItem *item = [menu addItemWithTitle:column.headerToolTip action:@selector(toggleTableColumn:) keyEquivalent:@""];
    item.state = [column isHidden] ? NSOffState : NSOnState;
    item.representedObject = column;
  }
  tableView.headerView.menu = menu;
```